# How to access entire row by cell address or value in excel?

Tags: excel

I have two sheets in excel.

First is MarkSheet of whole class.
[image]

And second is IndividualResultCard. 
[image]

I place role number of student or it's cell address in IndividualResultCard sheet and want to access complete row record.

Please give me its formula.

Is it possible without visual basic procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve all this by using the `Roll No.` as your reference, for this you should use a `VLOOKUP`

In Sheet **IndividualResultCard** enter my formula in to the following cells:

C7 (name) paste `=VLOOKUP($C$6,[MarkSheet.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$4:$H$100,2,FALSE)`

C8 (father) paste `=VLOOKUP($C$6,[MarkSheet.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$4:$H$100,3,FALSE)`

Here I am changing only the `col_index_num` which is the column you wish to return in your **MarkSheet**.

[image]

From here you should be able to tweak this `VLOOKUP` to return your marks.

Here is a detailed explanation of a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)